# How to set C++ breakpoint in eclipse when source is compiled with ccache?

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging, ccache

Recently, our development team is starting to use ccache to do faster compile (the compile is done from sandbox /usr/x).

Now, when I compile from my sandbox (/usr/y), and try to set a breakpoint in the code in Eclipse (GDB (DSF) process launcher), it fails to find the file.
Further investigation shows that Eclipse gdb uses the complete path of the file to set a breakpoint (e.g. b /usr/y/untouchedFile.cpp:1234), but the actual path (in the gdb debugger) is actually /usr/x/untouchedFile.cpp.

The only thing that works is to set a breakpoint on the console by typing it, and do a source file mapping when the breakpoint is hit.

I would like to set the breakpoint by clicking on the code line (which used to work before ccache).

I was wondering if there is a way to get around this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be handled by remapping debug-info.

- During compiling, add compile flags: `-fdiagnostics-absolute-paths -fdebug-prefix-map=/usr/y=/usr/x`
- During debugging, add `set substitute-path "/usr/x" "/usr/y"` into your gdbinit